# Onclick in website gallery only on iphone/ipad has mistake

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css

I have a problem with gallery on my website onlY WHEN is my website responsive. This is a link:

www.alexaworkshop.com

Problem is when I click on thumb android devices adn PC open biger picture from gallery normal but iphone open biger picture AND thumb stay active. That is a big problem because the big picture is opened by thumb. You can test it in gallery on my website with iphone.

[image]

on second click thumb desapears and biger picture is ok, But I dont know why onclick thumb stay active and plaster big picture. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to do is, set a `z-index` for both the Thumb and the large image so that they won't overlap even if there is a bug within your jquery.

Simply add something like this, but with your custom classes applied:

```
.thumb {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.image {
  z-index: 10;
}
```